# Pytest mocker patch Attribute:Error 'function' object has no attribute 'patch'

Tags: python, pytest, api-design

I'm trying to mock another method I've created using mocker.patch.object. However I get the AttributeError. New to using mocker but haven't seen an example that can help with this condition.

Tried different ways of calling the method from mocker.

within tests/test_unit.py

```
from pytest_mock import mocker

class TestApp:

 def setup_method(self):
        self.obj = ClassApi()

 def test_class_api_method(self, client):

        return_value = {'name': 'test'}
        mocker.patch.object(self.obj, 'method_to_mock')
        mocker.result(return_value)
```

within project/services

```
class ClassApi:

       def method_to_mock(self, input1):
         ...
        return result
```

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'patch'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with Pytest-Mock but based on a look at the docs you should be using `mocker` as a fixture. So you function should look like this:

```
 def test_class_api_method(self, client, mocker):

        return_value = {'name': 'test'}
        mocker.patch.object(self.obj, 'method_to_mock')
        mocker.result(return_value)
```

pytest automatically provides the argument mocker to the test function when it is run so there is no need to import it.

Comment: what does it mean to be a fixture and why does this work?

Comment: A fixture is a construct from the pytest library. In practice you declare a function and decorate it with `@pytest.fixture()`. Now whenever you declare a test function, you can specify the fixture name (function name) as an argument and pytest will inject the result of calling the fixture function as an argument.

Comment: I guess passing it in to the test_function() as an argument is the only true way to evaluate mocker properly in order to be utilized as the OP intended. Importing doesn't work because... (well I'm not sure why importing didn't work). Why didn't importing it work?

Comment: I just realized that a fixture is an additional feature of which pytest has its own implementation of. Therefore the way OP was using it was incorrect and there is a specific way to use fixtures to preserve the state of the object. Importing it does no good as it just a NOOP. I think I get it now.